# Strange coercions of properties in asyncData in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, nuxt.js, luxon

I'm trying to play with asyncData in Nuxt.js and it seems to me that not every property could be placed here as is. For example instances of Moment (moment.js) and DateTime (luxon), they are serialized into string:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
const moment = require('moment')
...
asyncData(context) {
    return {
      date1: moment(),
      date2: DateTime.local(),
      pureDate: new Date()
    }
  },
mounted() {
  console.log(typeof this.date1) // string ("2019-06-11T16:24:00.746Z")
  console.log(typeof this.date2) // string ("2019-06-13T19:24:00.748+03:00")
  console.log(typeof this.pureDate) // object (Thu Jun 13 2019 19:24:00 GMT+0300 (Moscow Standard Time))
}
```

some other complex objects properties raise warn:

```
Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs OpenPositions
```

someone please explain me this behavior

[sandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-nuxt-6wmo3)

[demo repo on github](https://github.com/khataev/async-data-nuxt)

Comment: I am also looking for the solution. The official repo's issue is marked as solved, but I couldn't find what the solve is.